# Access Forbidden running php

Tags: php, xampp

> You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.  If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/5.6.35

Comment: May be the link you entered is wrong, or your server configuration is misconfigured

Comment: Do you have an `index.php` file?

Answer (score -1):

Is that an console error or an error page that is shown by the browser?

If it is shown by the browser it may be caused by an .htaccess page authorization

Comment: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/5.6.35